# Google Analytics Integration issues

Tags: iphone, ios, google-analytics

I am not sure I fully understand the Google Analytics integration.  At least, what I read on Google's [SDK Page](http://code.google.com/mobile/analytics/docs/iphone/) and what I see in reality are not the same.

I've setup the Tracker in my applicationDidFinishLaunching method, with my key.

```
[[GANTracker sharedTracker] startTrackerWithAccountID:@"UA-xxxxxxxx-1"
                                       dispatchPeriod:30 // SENDS EACH 30 SECONDS.
                                             delegate:self];

NSError *error;
if (![[GANTracker sharedTracker] setCustomVariableAtIndex:1
                                                     name:@"iPhone"
                                                    value:appVersion
                                                withError:&error]) {
    // Handle error here
    ALog("Google Analytics Error: %@", error);
}


if (![[GANTracker sharedTracker] trackPageview:@"/app_did_finish_Launching"
                                     withError:&error]) {
    // Handle error here
    ALog("Google Analytics Error:%@", error);
}
```

I am using a delegate to ensure that the dispatch is firing, and it is, and each time it says it is successful.

```
- (void)trackerDispatchDidComplete:(GANTracker *)tracker
                  eventsDispatched:(NSUInteger)eventsDispatched
              eventsFailedDispatch:(NSUInteger)eventsFailedDispatch {
    DLog(@"events dispatched: %d, events failed: %d", eventsDispatched, eventsFailedDispatch);
}
```

Question 1:
I am trying to see this over WIFI, with a proxy I've setup between my iPhone and the web.  I see nothing that looks like Google analytics traffic.  Should I expect to see anything?

Question 2:
Its been 24 hrs, and I don't see anything on the Google Analytics site.  Should I see something?  I've had success with this implementation only when I set the dispatchPeriod to 0, and manually call dispatch in the code.
        BOOL success = [[GANTracker sharedTracker] dispatch];

But I really don't want to do this in a shipping app version.

What am I doing wrong?  Do I need to call dispatch manually?  The SDK implied you only call the dispatch if you want to send it manually (without batching the sends).  Am I understanding this correctly?

Thanks for your help.

-Yenyi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it takes a long time to update.  More than 24 hrs.  But it does update.  In the end, decided to go with Flurry, the API was just cleaner.